# What would be the sea level rise if all fossil fuel resources are burned?

Tags: climate-change, sea-level, climate-models

[Tokarska et al. (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1038/nclimate3036), a *Nature* article from a team of the University of Victoria, predicted a global temperature increase of 7±2.5°C and 17.2±2.5°C at the equator and at the poles respectively if all proven fossil carbon resources are burned (about 5 trillion tons of carbon).

What would be the sea level rise with this temperature?

Answer (score 1):

At the upper end of that range, all ice on Earth would melt.

That would *ultimately* give roughly 70 metre sea level rise from melting ice alone, but it may take thousands of years before it reaches equilibrium.

Add a bit to that to account for the thermal expansion of sea water.

Comment: In your ice melt calculation, are you counting only landlocked ice? Floating ice melt doesn't raise sea level.

Comment: @nmtoken Sorry, still need to expand on this answer.  From memory, Greenland would lead to around 6 metre SLR and Antarctica around 60 metre.  Sea ice melt indeed does not raise sea level, however, thermal expansion does and I have much less of a feel how bad that may be compared to land ice melt.

Comment: Citation needed.